# Play JFugue pattern in an infinite loop for a metronome

Tags: jfugue

How do I a produce an infinite loop using a JFugue pattern. I tried the following

- while loop
- for loop with a high counter

In both cases, weird sounds get produced which are overlapped. When I run with a small counter like 10 in a for loop, it works fine.

I need a pattern to run infinitely until the player is stopped by calling player.close() by an user action (say from UI).

Comment: I also tried pattern.repeat(WITH_A_HIGH_NUMBER). This also has the same effect with jumbled notes.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a specific way to make a pattern run forever. This is partly because JFugue compiles music strings into MIDI code, so a pattern that ran forever would just be a infinitely-long MIDI file. Of course, if you use a specific number of times to repeat a pattern, the pattern could be too long or too short for your needs. The best option might be to look into JFugue's RealtimePlayer class, and create a separate thread that keeps playing sections of the metronome pattern while the thread is still active.

Let me know if that helps you get on the right path!